# Accessing NSString properties of a Core Data entity

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsstring

I'm moving my initial steps in the Core Data realm (and I'm quite new to iPhone development, too) and I found a behavior I cannot explain.
I declared a subclass of a NSManagedObject and defined a few properties, some of them of type NSString *, MyObject.h is something like:

```
@interface MyObject : NSManagedObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *contentFile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *contentPath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

Now, if I try to create an object instance and assign a value to the name property, when I try to print back the content of the property it seems it's mangled.
In the AppDelegate, where the whole Core Data stack is defined, I write:

```
MyObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject"                                                
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

newObject.name = @"Testing";
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %s\n", newObject.name]);
```

What I get in the output console is

```
2009-08-24 20:03:55.176 MyApp[15727:20b] Name: ‡}00»
```

I can't understand if I'm doing something wrong or if I forgot something. Anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `%@` format specifier in `stringWithFormat:`, since `NSString` is an Objective-C object:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\n", newObject.name]);
```

`%s` is used for C-strings (`char*`s). For more info look at [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

The correct format specifier for Objective-C objects is `%@`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %@, not %s.  %s is for char* strings.  You're passing in an objective-c object.